# CSS max() function alternative

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to set the `min-height` of a HTML element to the maximum of two values, but unfortunately css doesn't support `max()`.
Here's my css code:

```
#content{ min-height:calc( 100% - 100px); }
```

The other value is constant number (`400px`). I think I have to use JS, but I cant figure out how to do that.
Here is my JS code:

```
function layout(){
    var y = document.getElementById("content");
    y.style.minHeight = Math.max(parseInt(y.style.minHeight), 400).toString + "px";
}
window.onload = layout;
window.onresize = layout;
```

`alert(parseInt(y.style.minHeight))` gives me `naN`.

What am I doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: Because `y.style.minHeight` is giving back: `calc( 100% - 100px)`, which can't be parsed into an number by parseInt.

Comment: @Mouser, actually, `y.style.minHeight` returns a null string (which is also invalid input for `parseInt`).

Comment: @RickHitchcock true, if set via JavaScript it will return something, comment still valid though :-). Thanks

Comment: @OP you should look into `getComputedStyle` to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't determine a direct way to get the calculated result of the `min-height` style.

But the following function assigns it to the `height` of the element, from which we can get it as the element's new `offsetHeight`.

The function then restores the original `height` of the element:

```
function layout() {
  var y = document.getElementById('content'),
      h = y.offsetHeight;

  y.style.height = getComputedStyle(y).getPropertyValue('min-height');
  y.style.minHeight = Math.max(y.offsetHeight, 400) + 'px';
  y.style.height = h + 'px';
} //layout
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mjdzgLrt/)